# MySQL, SUM the column of a table view

Tags: php, mysql, database, sum

This question may be miss comprehended, what I have done is created a column with a column view (not a full table view).

For example:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS <Field1>, <Field2>, <Field3>, Hour(TIMEDIFF(<Field2>, <Field3>)) as <Field4> FROM <TableName>
```

The fourth field (`<Field4>`) with the time diff does not get sent to the database.

Now what I want to do is use the sum formula on `<Field4>`, but I am unsure on how to do this without it being saved to the database.

Any Ideas?

EDIT:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS Date, Start, Finish, Hour(TIMEDIFF(Start, Finish)) as HoursTest FROM Hours
```

Here is my actual select statement.

Comment: SELECT doesn't save anything to the database. the SUM() function you have to combine it with the GROUP BY statement.

Comment: have you got an example?

Comment: What is it exactly that you want the sum from? Whats the common field, e.g. a date field

Comment: <field4> (an integer i.e. 6,7,8,9)in the example is the view i created (that column only), once the table is displayed i want to then calculate the total of that view column <field4>.

Comment: So per single record? Some basics: `SELECT SUM(field1+field2) as field4 FROM table` 
More records (find a common value of a colomn) `SELECT SUM(field1+field2) as field4 FROM table GROUP by field3`

Comment: can't do this read my edit, as you can see 'start' and 'finish' are time formatted and the difference is then calculated for the 'Hours' field, which i then want to SUM

Comment: So you calculate the difference per record and THAT you want to sum it up as 1 number and not per record?

Comment: yh i want to sum <HoursTest> field as a single total (<HoursTest> is a time difference value which returns an integer to the field named HourTest).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I think you want to save the select statement as a view, then do the sum from the view.

so

create view mynewviewname as

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS , , , Hour(TIMEDIFF(, )) as  FROM

then

SELECT sum(field4) from mynewviewname
where (whatever you want to query by)

Does that help?

Comment: THANKS, However, what i failed to mention was that this was and editable table, with this view would it be possible to update the view on refresh. because when i delete a record i.e. a shift would it delete it from the view or recreate the view on refresh.

Comment: it does help, ive got it working for the view, but my editable table doesn't correctly work due to the view not deleting the correct data.

Comment: Views are not always good for updating and/or deleting data.  What I would do is use the view for looking at the data, but when someone updates or deletes, create the update/delete code directly on the table(s), not the view.  Can you do that?